# Determine whether this sequence of functions converges uniformly or not.

Tags: uniform-convergence

I am stuck on determining whether this sequence of functions converges uniformly or not.

Let $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\log(\frac{1+x}{n})$ on the interval $\left(0,+\infty\right)$.
I can prove  that $\lim_{n\to +\infty} f_n(x)=0$  which means that the sequence  $f_n$ converges pointwise to the function $f(x)=0$.

Computing
$$\sup_{x\in\left(0,+\infty\right)}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\frac{1}{n}\sup_{x\in\left(0,+\infty\right)}|\log(\frac{1+x}{n})|,$$ let $h_n(x)=\log(\frac{1+x}{n})$ so the derivative fixing $n$ is $\frac{1}{x+1}>0$  for $x\in\left(0,+\infty\right)$.

Is it enough to say that
this sequence of functions converges uniformly or not? Im I totally wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you type `\sup` and `\log` to get $\sup$ and $\log$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$, $f_n(ne^n-1)=1$. So,$$\sup_{x\in(0,\infty)}\bigl|f_n(x)-f(x)\bigr|\geqslant1,$$and therefore the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: It seems that $f_n(e^n-1)=1-\frac{\log(n)}{n}$. Am I right?

Comment: @RobertZ Yes. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your time!